# Flaw in checking HTTP 500 error HttpUrlConnection Java

Tags: java, http, httpclient, httpurlconnection, httpexception

My issue is with `status != 200` , when I run this script (3) different times, it'll print out the value for `if{}` (1) times, the `else{}` (1) time, and the `catch{}` another.

I am simply trying to just print out in the `if(status != 200 || showTitleAttr == null || showTitleAttr == "")` the system.out.println(); message if the HTTP Error is not an HTTP 200 Error code. 
The logic makes sense, but it is still not working all the time and falling into the `catch{}` block. I'm starting to think it is a problem with the variable `status` instead.

Thank you.

**Small update**
even if I try: `conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK` it seems to not change which block it falls into.. (1) time each for `if{}`, `else{}`, `catch{}`

The error I receive when it hits the `catch{}` block is:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL
```

**Q:** Is there a better way to be checking for an HTTP error code that is anything than an HTTP 200 Error?

**The code:**

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        HttpException HttpExc = new HttpException();
        try {
                // setup Show Title Parser
                DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();

                // Set the Url to Parse and assign to object
                String UrlToParse = "urlishere.com";
                    URL obj = new URL(UrlToParse);

                // Try opening a http connection the the url above
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                int status = conn.getResponseCode();    

                // Setup parser
                parser.parse(UrlToParse);  
                Document doc = parser.getDocument();

                // Get the document's root XML node
                NodeList PGRoot = doc.getChildNodes();

                // Navigate down the hierarchy to get to the program node
                Node comp = getNode("ProgramGuideWCSResponse", PGRoot);
                Node PG = getNode("programGuide", comp.getChildNodes() );
                Node Programs = getNode("programs", PG.getChildNodes() );
                Node IndivdualProgram = getNode("program", Programs.getChildNodes() );
                NodeList nodes = IndivdualProgram.getChildNodes();
                //String execType = getNodeAttr("programTitle", exec);

                // Assign the Show Title to the NodeValue from traversing
                String showTitleAttr = getNodeValue("programTitle", nodes);

                // check to if the fetched Show Title isn't: 1) Returned bad error code 2) is null or 3) is empty 
                    // if it is... display the default value for title and exit.
                    // otherwise, print the Program Title.

                if(status != 200 || showTitleAttr == null || showTitleAttr == ""){
                    System.out.println("You’re watching XX Plus");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                else{
                    System.out.println("Program title is: " + showTitleAttr);
                }

        }
            catch(HttpException e){
                e.getStackTrace();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("You’re watching XX Plus");
                System.exit(0);
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Try changing this `showTitleAttr == ""` to this `showTitleAttr.equals("")`.  Not sure if that's causing your issue though

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that doesn't resolve the issue though with detecting Http errors as outlined above.

Comment: What is the exception stack trace when it hits the catch block?

Comment: Please see updated post above

Comment: You are calling parser.parse(UrlToParse) without checking the status first. If status is 500 (error), probably parser.parse(UrlToParse) will throw an exception.

Comment: @Chuidiang - an answer and a code snippet would help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check status before start to parse...

```
    URL url = new URL(UrlToParse );
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    int status = con.getResponseCode();
    if (status == 200){
        parser.parse(UrlToParse);  
        ....
    } else {
        // status is not 200
    }
```